# UV Unwrap - follow active quads

Tags: texturing, uv

I am currently struggling with the concept of UV unwrapping in Blender. I have recently come across the method "follow active quads" and, while I have used it successfully, I do not fully understand how it works. I am unable to find an explanation for how this unwrap method works online.

Can anyone offer a good way to visualise this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow Active Quads will extend the selected mesh UVs depends on the angle of the edges of active Quad.

[image]

Unwraping a mesh that doesn't have a UV map will set the active face mapped to the full size of the UV window and extent the rest of the faces accordingly.