# Brush omitting some parts when texture-painting

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

I don't understand why the brush works so randomly with this model. Did I set up something wrong in UV or is it something with the model?

I tried fiddling around the bleed settings and after unchecking "normal" it seemed to work a little better but still not good enough.

See gifs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdZVy.jpg
[image]

[image]

Comment: does the object have a mirror modifier? you need to apply it to paint the other side.

Comment: It had one, but it was already applied.

Comment: This sometimes happens due to perspective distortion.. It doesn't necessarily mean this is the case though. Try switching viewport to orthographic with Numpad 5 and see how it paints

Comment: I tried switching to orthographic but same result unfortunately.

Comment: Not enabled. I added .blend file.

Comment: I don't get any strange behaviour other than quite strong [texture distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilBxr.jpg) due to UV map distortion and unapplied non-uniform scale of the object. Try using Ctrl+A in Object mode, then reunwrap it with either Follow Active Quads or manually.

Comment: It doesn't let me use Follow Active Quads. It says "Report: No active face". With Lightmap Pack it gets way better but it's still too distorted sometimes. I'm not sure what to do manually because even if I wanted to correct the UV map, the Lightmap Pack leaves it quite well unwrapped.

Comment: The Lightmap Pack is UV map where each face is separated from others. It might work sometimes but in general is avoided because there won't be any possibility to correct the texture or add something to it once it's ready. Regarding Follow Active Quads - that message tells what it tells, it needs active face (select one with Right Click), see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32504/uv-unwrap-follow-active-quads. What I meant in general is that UV map from the example file should be redone for any expected unwrap.

Comment: Ok, now I tried with Follow Active Quads but same result (see: https://imgur.com/a/mwKUa). It's happening with every single model I create. I'm not sure what's wrong but the UV map seems ok, or isn't it?

Comment: The UV map is not quite visible there, but brush must be able to draw on the texture mapped with any unwrap. As it worked for me with your file it's not really clear what else could be wrong aside from unapplied scale and uv map as written above.

Comment: OK, that was the key. I had no idea scale had to be applied before unwrapping but it seems all my models are being unwrapped fine now after applying first scale and the brush works now as expected. Thanks a lot!